# With .Net Remoting is there any way to modify the remote object before making it accessible?

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

I have two processes that are communicating via `.Net remoting`, process `A` and `B`. I want that process `A` modifies a `List` and than send it to process `B`.

I have the following code (both processes share the same code):

```
namespace MyProcess
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Process A modifies List
            if(process A){
                changeList();
                createOutputList();
            }
            //Process B gets the List 
            if(process B){
                OutputListObject op = retrieveOutputList();
                op.getList();
            }           
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        void changeList()
        {
            //Some modification
        }

        OutputListObject retrieveOutput()
        {
            TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel();
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

            OutputListObject op = (OutputListObject)Activator.GetObject(
                typeof(OutputListObject),
                "tcp://localhost:10001/MyRemoteOperator");

            return op;
        }

        void createOutput()
        {
            TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(10001);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
                typeof(OutputListObject),
                "OutputList",
                WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
        }

    }

    public class OutputListObject : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public List<String> getList()
        {
            //return the modified list by Process A
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your question "how can modifications to a list made on my remote endpoint (proc B) get made visible to the sender (proc A)" ?

Comment: @PhillipH Nope, I want the sender (A) to modify an object and then send it to the receiver (B) using .NET Remoting

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the info! I found out just now another method `RemotingServices.Marshal`. Is there any difference from `MarshalByRefObject`?